# Hyperplane perpendicular to a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let's say that I am working in the Euclidean Space $\mathbb{R^n}$ for some fixed $n$. I give you a fixed vector $\alpha$ in this space, I want to know how to define the notion of "the hyperplane perpendicular to $\alpha$". My guess here is that it should be the orthogonal complement of $\alpha$ i.e. the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R^n} | \alpha^Tx=0\}$. Also it would be great if someone could clarify the notion of a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ being perpendicular to a vector $\alpha$. Again my guess is that each vector in the set $A$ is perpendicular/orthogonal to $\alpha$ ($A\subseteq \alpha^\bot$).

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful to start by clarifying the notion of the hyperplane of a vector space (that is not necessarily finite-dimensional like $\mathbb R^2$). Let $E$ be a vector space, say over the field $\mathbb R$ of real numbers. A hyperplane $H$ of $E$ is a vector subspace $H$ of $E$ such that $E=H\oplus D$, ie $E$ is the direct sum of $H$ and $D$, where $D$ is a vector line ( $\exists u \in E- \{0\}, D=\mathbb R u)$. *No more no less*.

Then you will find in any course on vector spaces that

the hyperplanes of a vector space of dimension $2$ are the vector lines $\color{green}{(1)}$

$H$ is a hyperplane of $E$ if and only if there exists a linear form $f:E\to K$ such that $H=\{x\in E: f(x)=0\}$$\color{red}{(2)}$

Then take $n=2$ and consider Euclidean space $(\mathbb R^2,+,.,(.|.))$. Take for example $\alpha:=(3,2)$. Consider $$f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R,x=(\xi,\eta) \mapsto \alpha^Tx:=((\xi,\eta)|(3,2))=3\xi+2\eta$$ $f$ is a linear form. So, according to $\color{red}{(2)}$, $$H:=\{x=(\xi,\eta)\in \mathbb R^2: f(x)=0\}=\{(\xi,\eta)\in \mathbb R^2: 3\xi+2\eta=0\}$$ is an hyperplane. Then, according to $\color{green}{(1)}$, $H$ is a vector line. Thus, we find many results that we have known for a long time and that we can even easily illustrate. I'll let you work the same way in $\mathbb R^3$ or even in $\mathbb R^4$;
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, in the case you just presented, is the statement "the vector $\alpha$  i.e. $(3,2)$ is orthogonal to the hyperplane $H$" a valid statement?

Comment: Yes more generally, tous parts M,N are said orthogonal if every $x\in M$ is orthogonal to every $y\in N$